# how to cut out connection for aws sdk s3 after predefined time?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ceph

I'm using `aws-sdk` module in my `node` app,
specifically the `S3` library, to write to a `ceph` cluster.

The application upload fixed size files periodically.
The ceph perform sharding sometimes, which cause the http upload request to stall for 500 seconds.
How can I cancel those requests for buckets that performing sharding?
How can I set a timeout for, say 2 seconds, for all the uploads?

Comment: do you want to set it in your ceph cluster or in your aws sdk client?

Comment: I prefer aws sdk client as i dont have full control over the cluster

Comment: @natdev can you share how you connect to Ceph using AWS S3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching the web for a long time, I found this [abort](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#abort-property) function.

So, if it help anyone, this is how I implemented it:

```
const upload = (bucket, key, body, timeout = 2000) => {
  const request = this.s3.upload({Bucket: bucket, Key: key, Body: body})
  setTimeout(request.abort.bind(request), timeout)
  return request.promise()
}
```

If `timeout` passed, then an `Error` is thrown with `RequestAbortedError` code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timeout` in `httpOptions`. example:

```js
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', httpOptions: {timeout: 2000}});
```

Comment: I did it, it didn't work... as documented, it states that it closes `idle` connection where there is no traffic, but as it turns out, the client doesn't close the connection upon waiting for the response

Comment: @natdev Maybe there is a chunk transferring. If you want to timeout on the whole request I think you should implement it by node js and aws sdk doesn’t have this option.

Comment: I found a way to do it, check my answer